# Set a users location on iOS app

Tags: ios

What I'm trying to do is set the location of my iPhone through my app. The only thing I've been able to do is in xcode go to debug->simulate location. My question is, is it possible to set the location without using xcode.

Thanks!

Comment: you running it in simulator right?

Comment: I have it running on my actual phone through xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do some modification when you achieve your locations.

You can use a viewController with a map view to choose a location.

when you want to simulate a location, just achieve from your simulated locations.

I have wrote a similar function before, you can make a reference.
[The source codes](https://github.com/lovesunstar/stkitdemo/blob/master/STKitDemo/Classes/Modules/Settings/Debug/STDLocationPickerController.h)

And the operations start->TabBarController->The Third Tab->The right Bar Item->The Second Row in the First Section->Long press to pick a location

If you have a locationManager, it will be very convenient. like

```
coordinate = [STDLocationPickerController cachedFakeLocationCoordinate]

if (coordinate.long * lat > 0) {
    continue your logic
} else {
    locate or pick a location
}
```